# Python-Displaying Query results in QTreeView

Tags: python, plugins, pyqt

I am working with python plugins for qgis.I am using python2.5 and pyqt4 designer.I used QTreeView on my .ui  file.
I wanted to display all the tables from database into QTreeView as the result of the query.
The query is as follows:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'")
```

I am using PostgresSQL as database.Database connection is done using psycopg2 tool.
How to display result of above query into QTreeView in python??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTreeView` requires a Model/View framework, so you need to provide a model to work with it. If you are set on using `psycopg2`, you need to build and populate your own model by sub-classing [`QAbstractItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html) from that query.

Alternatively, and more easily, you can use the Qt's [`QSql`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtsql-module.html) module. It supports PostgreSQL and provides ready-made models (like `QSqlTableModel`, `QSqlRelationalTableModel` or `QSqlQueryModel`) that you can use with `QTreeView`.